# Flutter Just shows blank cross icon even though image is present

Tags: android, ios, flutter, sharedpreferences

I am having the following problem while getting image from the shared preferences. Image is present but I am getting just the blank cross icons. I tried with other methods but with every try I am getting just the Blank cross icons. I am getting image from either gallery or camera.

```
 void takePhoto(ImageSource source) async {
      final image = await _picker.getImage(
        source: source,
      );
      if (image!= null) {
      final imageTemporary = File(image.path);
      setState(()  =>
        this.image = imageTemporary);
      final bytes = await image.readAsBytes();
      final base64Image = base64Encode(bytes);
      print(base64Image);
      await prefs?.setString('myImageKey', base64Image);
    }
    }

    Future<File?> showData() async{

        setState(() {
          final base64Image = prefs?.getString('myImageKey');
          if (base64Image != null) {
            final bytes = base64Decode(base64Image);
            this.imageFile = File.fromRawPath(bytes);
          }

        });
        return this.imageFile;
      }


Getting image here
       Container(

        height: 300,
              width: 300,
              child:
              FutureBuilder<File?>(
                future: showData(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    print("image selected");
                    return
                      Image.file(snapshot.data!);
                  } else {
                    return Text("No images selected");
                  }
                },
              ),


          )
```